# How to use Javascript every() method to check one element against all other in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My situation is this, I have a **Point** object thats has an **'x'** and **'y'** properties. Point also have a getDistance() method that calculates the distance between two Points.

Example:

```
if (position.getDistance(prevPosition) > 10) {
    // add new Point
} else {
    // don't add new Point
}
```

I have an array of Points and I need to check if the new Point is too close to all the other Points in the array. looking at the Javascript documentation the **every()** method seems to be the go to function to use but I'm struggling implementing it.

```
function getDistance(position, prevPosition) {
    return position.getDistance(prevPosition) > 10;
}

if (points.every(position)) {
    // add new Point
} else {
    // don't add Point
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: `points.every(point => point.getDistance(position) > 10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.every` takes *a function*, and every element of the array gets passed to that function (in your case, every point gets passed) and then you have to return a predicate (whether it is far away):

```
  points.every(position => position.getDistance(newPoint) > 10)
```

Comment: Say the points array is an array of objects but I need to compare just the position property of each element of the array, is that possible?

Comment: Sure, thats a regular property access.

Comment: Yes, I sort it out by calling: segments.some(position => position.point.getDistance(newPoint) > 10) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use the `every` function:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];

let areAllPositive = a.every(num => num > 0); // true
let areAllOdd = a.every(num => num % 2); // false

console.log(areAllPositive);
console.log(areAllOdd);
```

In your use case, it would be

`let allPointsAreFarEnough = points.every(point => point.getDistance(position) > 10)`